# Servlet API Casting issue with Struts 2 with Open JDK and Tomcat 9.0

Tags: java, java-8, struts2, apache-tomee

[image: Package comparison between TomEE servlet ApI vs Tomcat Servlet API]I am in the process of migrating the Structs 1 & EJB 2.0 , JDK 1.6 websphere application to Open JDK 1.8, Structs 2.5 and TomEE application server.

1st step in migration, I had mimicked only one use case of the project pointed to Open JDK 1.8 and now in the process of upgrading from Struts 1.1 to Struts 2.5 by adding the dependent jars one by one.

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>project</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>project</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>eRFQ</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
    <!-- <servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.company.production.core.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>validate</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> -->
    
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/jsp/AuthorizationError.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

I have a simple home.jsp just with title

here is my struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources"
        value="com.toyota.owkmessaging.resources.ApplicationResources" />

    <package name="home" namespace="/home" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="homeForm" class="com.company.production.project.action.HomeAction" method="execute">
            <result name = "success">/Home.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
    
</struts>
```

I am deploying the above set up TomEE Plume 9.0. I am facing an issue when the Structs Filters are loaded from web.xml which is indirectly referring servlet-api (from tomcat lib directory) tomEE version of servlet-api(with Filter class packaged in jakarta.servlet.Filter) with package reference as per the below snapshot.

Error:

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [project]
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter cannot be cast to jakarta.servlet.Filter
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4536)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5173)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)

Aug 06, 2020 7:14:59 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Aug 06, 2020 7:14:59 AM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: Context [/eRFQ] startup failed due to previous errors
Aug 06, 2020 7:14:59 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
WARNING: Unexpected state during contextDestroyed: no ConfigManager instance in current ServletContext but one is expected to exist.
```

Are there any solutions to the above issue?

Comment: Missed a Big Note: TomEE 9.0.0-M1 is a milestone release, which targets the jakarta namespace. Applications using javax will not work on this release of TomEE 9. You may encounter issues - feedback on this release is encouraged and appreciated

Comment: You can upgrade servlet api jar and check for 4+ versions.